# firebase admin not import in google app engine

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-admin

I have install firebase admin in python2
here is the path

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/firebase_admin
```

It is working fine with core python and import successfully

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate('hfbi9-52dc3dd6bf.json')

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

user = firebase_admin.auth.create_user(
    email='user@example.com',
    email_verified=False,
    phone_number='+15555550100',
    password='secretPassword',
    display_name='John Doe',
    photo_url='http://www.example.com/12345678/photo.png',
    disabled=False
)
```

but when i import these module in google app engine and run this it not found.

Comment: In the standard environment you need to [vendor in](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#copying_a_third-party_library) your dependencies inside your app code, having them installed on your local machine doesn't count.

Comment: I have done this but getting new error

Comment: ('Connection aborted.', error(13, 'Permission denied'))

Comment: how can i solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493137/google-appengine-incapable-of-performing-the-requested-operation